# Newbie Posting Style Tips

Tags: discussion

### Before Posting:

1. define your question as *conceptual* or *technical*.  To me, a conceptual question runs along the lines of "I have problem X, and I'm trying to find a decent way to implement a solution", whereas a technical question is more "I'm trying to implement a solution, what is this error/why doesn't this code snippet work".
2. Always find some way to provide a concrete example (I've learned this the hard way).  If your problem involves data, make sure you provide some sample data in the exact same format as your working data.  If your question is more conceptual, at least include some psuedo-code describing what you need your program to do

### In A Post

1. Succinctness is your best friend.  make sure that you have a succinct description of the problem with a working example/demonstration
2. make sure any methods/functions/characters use the `code` font to improve readability.

   - bad=I'm running a for loop that prints output
   - good=I'm running this `for` loop that `print`s output
3. If there are multiple steps to your problem, make sure you are breaking them down using using lists/headers etc.

### After a post

1. Don't run out the door or head to a meeting.  Users are usually pretty quick to jump in with answers or questions, and quick response to their questions means quick answers for you.

Comment: Questions should be questions, not answers.  (This is ironic from a post providing suggestions on how to ask questions.)

Comment: Your example use of code blocks uses code blocks improperly...

Comment: Is soliciting feedback with a discussion tag not appropriate?

Comment: In this form, no, not really.  Even on meta it should still be in a question/answer format.

Comment: Welp, good to know.  Should I take this question down then?  What's the most appropriate course of action?

Comment: Well, I'd start out by reading through all of the material already provided to users on how to ask questions, because there's a *lot* of it, between the help center, the FAQ, and other meta questions.  Most of your points already exist there.  If there is something that you feel is missing from one of those sources, and you feel strongly that the information is of the utmost importance, consider starting a discussion to propose including something in one of those canonical sources.

Comment: What about capitalizing words? Like titles? That bothers me for some reason.

Comment: @SeanWM In terms of priorities for what people should be focusing on, that's pretty far down on the priority list.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, I know. I was intentionally trying to be difficult because all the information new users need is right [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help). I don't know why people feel the need to post about it. Not sure what you can write about? [Here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Not sure how to write a good question? [This should help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is pretty much [already covered here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  For those who need lots of help, they can find it at the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

I see the good intentions of writing this post but I really don't see it helping much. New users have all the information they need to make positive contributions to SO. And when I say all, I literally mean [**all**](https://stackoverflow.com/help). When you see a post that isn't  on-topic or lacks quality just direct the user to the help section. There's no point re-writing what has already been written.

The help sections I commonly link to:

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Also, your question isn't a question. In the future I'd recommend writing an actual question and then answering it. It's [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: New users have all the information they need, and then they don't read it.

Comment: @gunr2171 Oh I know. You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink.